# How to remove all numbers and commas from a string except any number immediately preceded by $ using R?

Tags: regex, r

I would like to remove all numbers and commas from a string except any number that is immediately preceded by $ and immediately followed by a comma.

For example, I have:

```
str = "1, $100-$1,000 2, $1001-$10,000 3, $10,001-$100,000"
```

I would like to obtain the following:

```
"$100-$1,000  $1001-$10,000  $10,001-$100,000"
```

I have tried to use `gsub` with a negative lookbehind

```
new_str = gsub("(?<!\\$)[0-9]*,", "", str)
```

However, this gives the following error message:

```
Error in gsub("(?<!\\$)[0-9]*,", "", str) : invalid regular expression '(<!\$)[0-9]*,', reason 'Invalid regexp'
```

It seems that the negative lookbehind is incorrectly coded, but I can't seem to figure out why. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: if all your strings are exactly like that, just split based on whitespace and select out the monies `x <- strsplit(str, ' ')[[1]]; x[grepl('\\$', x)]` and then paste it back together

Comment: add `perl=TRUE` to your `gsub` to get the look-ahead/behinds working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** This gives the desired answer in the case of the sample string:

```
gsub("\\d+, ", "", str)
## [1] "$100-$1,000 $1001-$10,000 $10,001-$100,000"
```

Visualization of regular expression

```
\d+,
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/oHaHERJ1A3Rc-ksI)

**2)** Here is a second approach:

```
library(gsubfn)

paste(strapplyc(str, "(\\$\\S+)", simplify = c), collapse = " ")
## [1] "$100-$1,000 $1001-$10,000 $10,001-$100,000"
```

Visualization of regular expression

```
(\$\S+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ngyyhuh2VMSZMCzX)

Answer (score 0):

you could use this pattern

```
(\$[0-9,-]+)|\d+,\s
```

and replace w/ `\1`
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/183)